# Laravel + React (Typescript/Javascript) - how to compiler any module with extensions file (js, jsx, ts, tsx)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, typescript

i have files:
root.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Container from './apps/Container'
import Wrap from './apps/Wrap'

export default class Root extends Component {

 render() {
 console.log('load root.tsx')
  return (
   <div>
    aaaa
    <Container />
    <Wrap />
   </div>
  )
 }
}
```

and file app.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import RootApplication from './root'
ReactDOM.render(<RootApplication />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

I'm already tried load two code at the same time
webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .ts('resources/js/app.tsx  ', 'public/js/')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

but it is redundant.
How to can i use one line code but can load module from file js jsx ts tsx